# Pentaho Kettle: Mailing the result of a transformation

Tags: report, pentaho, kettle

I am having a kettle job and transformation.

1. Transformation will write the result set of a select sql into a csv file.
2. job will get the result file and mail it to the user.

I need to mail only if the file consists any data, else should not mail the result to user.
or how to find the result of a transformation is empty or not(is there any file size validator job entry available?).
I am not able to find any job entries for this kind of conditioning.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Evaluate files metrics` job step in the Conditions branch. Set your condition on the Advanced tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your transformation to generate the file only if there is data and then use in your main job the `File exists?` step.